# CoffeeScript jQuery plugin and trying to call to external jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, coffeescript

I have the following (simple) CoffeeScript jQuery Plugin:

```
$ = jQuery

$.fn.extend
    schoolSelect: (options) ->
        settings = 
            apiUrl: '/api/v1'
            debug: false

        settings = $.extend settings, options

        log  = (msg) ->
            console?.log msg if settings.debug

        return @each ->
            @.dropkick
                change: (val, label) ->
                    log val
                    log label
```

And I call it in another CoffeeScript file like so:

```
$('.school_select').schoolSelect
        debug: true
```

But for some reason I keep getting the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLSelectElement> has no method 'dropkick'`

I am using the `DropKick`jQuery plugin for my HTML selects: http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/

How can I access the DropKick plugin within my CoffeeScript jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
    return @each ->
        @.dropkick
```

Needs to be

```
    return @each ->
        $(@).dropkick
```

In the context of a jQuery callback for each, `this` gives you back a raw DOM element (hence the warning about HTMLSelectElement), not a jQuery object.

If your plugin is calling another plugin, you need to ensure the setup for the DropKick plugin is done before you extend jQuery.

Comment: I knew it was something simple! Thanks for the help! It works like a charm now!